# JTable multiple instances

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, multiple-instances

I have a `JTable` that gets data added to it from another `JTable`.

Now I want to switch between `JTable`s according to the day selected in a `JComboBox`.

For example, if I choose Monday I add programs added to it then I select Tuesday from the `JComboBox` and a fresh `JTable` appears. If I go to Monday again the programs should still be there (until the program is closed).

How do I create multiple `JTable`s (the `JTable` remains the same) for the days and let the info remain there until program closure?

Here is an example to show you what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering the rows in an existing table seems easier. See [*Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for how to create a `RowFilter`, instances of which can be added to a `JComboBox` and applied in the combo's action listener.